# Why do I get the errors 'Missing number' and 'Illegal unit of measure'?

Tags: tables, multirow

The problem is in using the `\multirow` function. This is not the main document, the `\usepackage{multirow}` is already defined in the main document from which I compile. I can not see the error:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

%\caption{Types of UAS according to NATO Classification}\\

\hline

\textbf{Class} & \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Normal employment}& \textbf{Normal Operating     Altitude}& \textbf{Normal Mission Radius} & \textbf{Example platform}\\

\hline 

\multirow{3}{|l|}{Class I (less than $150$ kg)} & Small $>20$ kg & T & Up to 5000 $ft$ & 50 $km$ & Hermes 90, Luna\\

\hline

Mini 2-20 $kg$ & Tactical Sub-Unit & Up to 3000 $ft$ & 25 $km$ & AlDIN, dh3, DRAC, Eagle,   Raven\\

\hline

MICRO $<2$ $kg$ & Tactical PI (single operator) & Up to 200 $ft$ & 5 $km$ & Black Widow\\

\hline

Class II & Tactical & Tactical Formation & Up to 10.000 $ft$ & 200 $km$ & Aerostar, Hermes 450, iView 250, Ranger\\

\hline

\multirow{3}{|l|}{Class III ($>600 kg$)} & Strike/Combat &Strategic/National&Up to 65.000 $ft$ & Unlimited & bg\\

\hline

HALE (High Altitude Long Endurance) & Strategic & Up to 65.000 ft & Unlimited & Global Hawk\\

\hline

MALE (Medium Altitude Long Endurance) & Operational & Up to 45.000 ft & Unlimited & Predator B, Predator A, Harfang Heron\\

\hline

\end{tabular}
```

Comment: The second argument to `\multirow` is either `*` or a dimension, not a column specifier.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".